# Re-enter period before visa expires

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, study, visa-expiration

I have student visa which expires on 31 January 2020
After completing my studies in September 2019, i have traveled on vacation to my resident country.  When should i re-enter UK? Is there any specific time limit that i should re-enter?

Answer (score 10):

There is no time limit to re-enter other than your visa expiry date. Having left during your post-study period, on re-entry you will need to satisfy Border Force officials that you are returning for a permitted reason and will leave before your visa expires.

https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/822984/T4_Migrant_Guidance_August_2019_.pdf

**After you have finished your studies**

272. As part of your application you will receive an additional period of leave after you have finished your studies. The length of your post-study period will depend on your level of study and is set out in the sections ‘Length of time a Tier 4 (General) Student can come to the UK for’ and ‘Length of time a Tier 4 (Child) Student come to the UK for’.
273. Once your sponsor has confirmed that your studies are complete, and you are therefore in your post-study period, you may do the following:

• Enter and leave the UK

• Work full-time in the UK, if your conditions of leave permit you to
work

• Study in the UK

• Visit areas in the UK

• Apply to remain in the UK under an appropriate alternative route
(e.g. Tier 1 and Tier 2).

Section 274 states:
“Please be aware that if you do travel during your post-study period, Border Force officials will need to be satisfied when you are entering the UK that you will either complete the activity you intend to carry out and leave the UK before your visa expires, or that you will submit an in-time application to extend your leave in the UK. You should carry any documentation relevant with you when you travel to show to the Border Force officer if required.”

Comment: It might be a good idea to add a sentence following the first sentence to summarize section 274.